# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice, locationlistener

I am writing a program which fetches the users current latitude and longitude every 5 minutes. I am using `AlarmManager`  and i want to run the program background  so I am using `IntentService`.But when executing the program the following error occurs:

logcat

```
02-06 15:40:03.101: W/dalvikvm(17499): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4203c2a0)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:180)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:180)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:657)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:482)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at com.gpsshoppe.LocationFinder$CurrentLocatioFinder.doInBackground(LocationFinder.java:58)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at com.gpsshoppe.LocationFinder$CurrentLocatioFinder.doInBackground(LocationFinder.java:1)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-06 15:40:03.109: E/AndroidRuntime(17499):    ... 5 more
```

this is my class

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class LocationFinder extends IntentService {
    private Context mcontext;
    SharedPreferences shprefs;


    public LocationFinder() {
        super("LocationFinder");
        this.mcontext=this;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CurrentLocatioFinder lFinder=new CurrentLocatioFinder();
        lFinder.execute();

    }
public class CurrentLocatioFinder extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements LocationListener{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(location!=null){
        shprefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LocationFinder.this);


        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
        Log.i("Inside cLocation", ""+latitude);

        Editor edit=shprefs.edit();  
        edit.putString("Ltd", ""+latitude);
        edit.commit();

        double longitude=location.getLongitude();

        edit.putString("Lngtd", ""+longitude);
        edit.commit();
        LatLng lng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        Log.i("LatLng", ""+lng);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  } 

}
```

Comment: Where u initialized mcontext?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the callback handler for locationservice inside your AsyncTask implementation. The handlers will be executed in the thread where it was created, so in your case the location callback needs to be executed from your AsyncTask thread which it is not able to do. I suggest you move the locationservice handler to your main thread.
Let LocationFinder  implement the LocationListener interface.

Answer (score 0):

I just edit your class Try hope this works for you

```
public class LocationFinder extends IntentService {
    private Context mcontext;
    SharedPreferences shprefs;

    public LocationFinder() {
        super("LocationFinder");
        this.mcontext = this;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        CurrentLocatioFinder mCurrentLocatioFinder = new CurrentLocatioFinder();
        mCurrentLocatioFinder.attach();

    }

    public class CurrentLocatioFinder implements LocationListener {
        LocationManager locationManager;

        public void attach() {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location != null) {
                shprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LocationFinder.this);

                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Log.i("Inside cLocation", "" + latitude);

                Editor edit = shprefs.edit();
                edit.putString("Ltd", "" + latitude);
                edit.commit();

                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                edit.putString("Lngtd", "" + longitude);
                edit.commit();
                LatLng lng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Log.i("LatLng", "" + lng);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create AsyncTask in onHandleIntent, because its a background thread.

My suggestion is to forget about the IntentService, because it has no any addition in this case. You can launch your AsyncTask directly, there is no need to wrap it inside an IntentService.

However if you really want a Service, that cares about the Location handling, then you could do the same thing with a Service, since its onStartCommand method runs in the main thread.